# "no provisioned ios devices are available" on Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, provisioning, xcode4.2

I just installed Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard. I have iOS 5 on my iPhone but i receive this error when I'm trying to run an app on my iPhone. The provision profile is also OK, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Can someone please help me with this!

Regards,
Bogdan.

Comment: please explain what actual error you encountered??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please open your Organizer and check if the device is responding correctly to XCode, and if it is "Ready for development". A orange or red dot will indicate its status, and it should be able to give you a hint of what's wrong.

It's **Menu bar > Window > Organizer > Devices**

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I had to press a button there and then it become available.

Answer (score 1):

can you see any device in XCode?? if not then go to **Manage Scheme** and click on **Auto Create Scheme**. you will find the device.